# Animate marker in google map

Tags: java, android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm going to develop a location based game in android. I want to move a marker from one coordinate to other.Two points are in line! I'm trying to split the distance with points every 1m in order to create frames. Any help with the stracture of the class?

Thanks you

Comment: I know it's not a proper answer but you could have a look at the javascript sources for [animaps](http://www.animaps.com/pb/638004/2835/Showcase) and see how it's done there (click the play button for a demo).

Comment: That's it!! I want to do something like that in java!

Comment: Oh, I somehow missed the Android reference and assumed javascript. Oops!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Maps Android API v2, you may want to check out [Android Maps Extensions library](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/), which adds `animatePosition(LatLng)` method to `Marker`s.

You can see animated markers on the demo app here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.mg6.android.maps.extensions.demo